# Tokenizing a string

Tags: c, arrays, parsing

I am in the process of writing a C program that parses a string and tokenizing it by breaking the string characters into words that are seperated by white space. My question is when i run my current program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char input[20];

printf("Please enter your word:\n");

scanf("%c", &input);

printf("%c", input[1]);
return 0;

}
```

If i was to enter the word "This", i would expect to get back "h" when i run the program but instead i get a downwards pointing arrow. However, when the input is set to print out input[0] i get back a "T".

Edit: I have modified my code so that it prints out the whole string now which i will show below

```
int main()
{
char input[20];
printf("Please enter your words:\n");
scanf("%s", input);

printf("%s", input);
return 0;

}
```

My goal is to be able to break that string into chars that i can search through to find whitespace and thus being able to isolate those words for example, if my input was "This is bad" i'd like the code to print out
This

is

bad

Edit:
I have modified my code to fit one of these answers but the problem i run into now is that it won't compile

```
int main()
{
char input[20];
printf("Please enter your words:\n");
size_t offset = 0;
do
{
scanf("%c", input + offset);
offset++;
}
while(offset < sizeof(input) && input[offset - 1] != '\n');

}


printf("%c", input[]);
return 0;
```

Comment: Why are you printing the second element?

Comment: I was trying to make sure it all printed out correctly, sorry i just recently edited my question to make it more clear, the first element prints out correctly but the second does not.

Comment: The second element is undefined. It could print anything.

Comment: @self. how is it that the first element is defined then?

Comment: Because you wrote in it with your code, incorrectly, but still.

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux Because you read 1 character only (`%c`) so it stores it in `input[0]` which is the first element, but when you print `input[1]` it could print anything because you haven't set anything to `input` so it contains junk data by default or if you're lucky it'll be zeroes which would print out nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

1) `scanf("%c", input);` only set the first element of the array `input`.

2) `printf("%c", input[1]);` prints the second element of the array `input`, which has uninitialized data in it.

---

Solution:
Small state machine.  No limit on string size like 20.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int ch = fgetc(stdin);
  while (ch != EOF) {
    while (isspace(ch)) {

      // If only 1 line of input allowed, then add
      if (ch == '\n') return 0;;

      ch = fgetc(stdin);
    }
    if (ch != EOF) {
      do {
        fputc(ch, stdout);
        ch = fgetc(stdin);
      } while (ch != EOF && !isspace(ch));
      fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When i used this, it crashed after putting the input in

Comment: @Breon Thibodeaux typo and code correction made `fputc('\n', stdin);`.  Sorry long night.

Comment: oh definitely no need for apologies, at least you have this stuff down

Comment: although with the fixes if i was to type in "This is bad" it'll give me an output of "Thissad", so i'm guessing the spaces are erasing the characters after them

Comment: @Breon Thibodeaux Mistake again on my part `fputc('\n', stdout);`

Comment: thank you very much for your time, i will examine this code thoroughly and make sure i learn about what every element of this code does, thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%c", &input);` does not do what you think it does.

First of all, `%c` scans only a single character: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Second, array's name is already a pointer to it's first element, so stating `&input` you make a pointer to a pointer, so instead of storing your character in array's first element you store it in pointer to the array which is a very bad thing.

If you really want to use scanf, I recommend a loop:

```
size_t offset = 0;
do 
{
    scanf("%c", input + offset);
    offset++;
}
while(offset < sizeof(input) && input[offset - 1] != '\n');
```

Using `scanf("%s", input")` leaves you vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks if the word is longer than 20 characters http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

In my example I assumed, that you want to finish your word with a newline character.

EDIT: In scanf documentation is also a good example:

```
scanf("%19s", input);
```

It scans no more than 19 characters, which also prevent buffer overflow. But if you want to change input size, you have to change it two places.

Comment: Thank you, removing the & from input got me a step closer but what i'm trying to do specifically is to set the words i enter such as "This is bad" into seperate elements in to my input array, such that T would be the first element, h would be the second, and so on and so forth.

Comment: And that's exactly what the loop does. It reads one character, puts it in the array to index specified by offset (`input + offset` is the same as `&input[offset]`) and if it's not final character offset is incremented, so next character will be stored in next element and the process is repeated.

Comment: Oh my god, i'm sorry i didn't recognize that

Comment: That's ok :) Just choose the terminating character(s), I went for newline, but you may prefer space, tabulation, or any other. You can use multiple terminators if you prefer, just add more conditions in while statement.

Comment: So just so i'm clear on this, i'd remove my scanf statement and replace it with that loop?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget about `offset` variable initialized to 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

to tokenize your string. If you have your input in input[] array and want to tokenize the string accoring to whitespace character, you can do the following :

```
char *ptr;

ptr = strtok(input, " ");

while(ptr != NULL) {
   printf("%s\n", ptr);
   ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Only the first call to strtok() requires the character array as input. Specifying NULL in the next calls means that it will operate on the same character array.

Comment: There's also a "safer" reëntrant version … strtok-r (with an underscore, which my mobile won't type)…

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf` only picks up the first character, `input[1]` contains random garbage. Use `scanf("%19s", input)` instead.

Comment: suggest `scanf("%20s", input)` instead so it doesn't overflow.

Comment: Better, yes. (I don’t use `scanf` and never remember if the count includes the NUL, so I’ll chicken out and insert 19.)

Comment: In `scanf` examples at cplusplus.com they use `"%79s"` for an array of 80 bytes, so you were right to chicken out :)

Comment: @user9000 `"%19s"` is correct for `char input[20];`.

Comment: Actually, `%20x` is the correct one, try it by yourself, you'll see that it's fine.  Remember how C arrays work and you'll know why it works.

Comment: @user9000 The 19 is the number of characters to scan and an array of 20 is needed.  The C spec provide an example `int count; float quant; char units[21], item[21]; do { count = fscanf(stdin, "%f%20s of %20s", &quant, units, item);`  So maybe the C spec is wrong?  Try `char buf[10]; scanf("%4s", buf); printf("'%s'\n", buf);` and see that you can put 4 `char` in buf along with a `\0`.  The width needs to be at least 1 less than the buffer size.